# How can I set a minimum learning rate in lr_scheduler LambdaLR?

Tags: python, pytorch, learning-rate

I'm using `LambdaLR` as a learning rate function:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = torch.nn.Linear(2, 1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
lambda1 = lambda epoch: 0.99 ** epoch
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lambda1, last_epoch = -1)

lrs = []


for i in range(2001):
    optimizer.step()
    lrs.append(optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"])
    scheduler.step()

plt.plot(lrs)
```

[image]

I'm trying to set a min learning rate so it won't go to 0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The new learning rate is always calculated like that:

[image: LRepoch = LRinitial * Lambda(epoch):]

And with the inital learning rate they mean the first one, not the last one used.

That means we can just write:

```
INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
your_min_lr = 0.0001

lambda1 = lambda epoch: max(0.99 ** epoch, your_min_lr / INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE)
```

Then you get `your_min_lr` back when `INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE * (0.99 ** epoch)` gets too small because `INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE * your_min_lr / INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE` equals just `your_min_lr`.